# Attempt to request Access token for Zoom OAuth API results in invalid redirect url

Tags: python, oauth, python-requests, zoom-sdk

I am using the tutorial in the following link to create an Access Token automatically for Oauth Zoom API: [OAuth with Zoom](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/auth/oauth)

The issue lies in the first step where I am required to provide a redirect link. Everytime I try to make a post request to their API, I get an error

> "Invalid redirect url (4,700)".

This token which I desire will be needed to use the rest of the functions in the API. The token can be generated manually, but I desire it to be automated for my process. I am using python requests for this.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
 'content-type': "application/json"
}

url = "https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ulDD9pB4RG28mFrX0jnIQ&redirect_uri=https://zoom.us" 

res = requests.post(url,headers = headers)

print(res.text)
```

I have looked this issue up everywhere, but I haven't been able to find an answer to my issue.

Any help for this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the documentation for  [Oauth 2.o Authorization](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/auth/oauth)  you will find that the Redirect Uri is defined as folows

[image]

So the redirect URI is the endpoint on **your** system which is designed to handle the oauth response, it must have also been added to the Oauth app settings when you set up your project on zoom.

You have added `https://zoom.us` unless your a developer at zoom i dont think that you can have a app located at `https://zoom.us` designed to handle the oauth response.

I would expect a redirect uri to look something like `https://www.yourdomain.com/zoom/oauthcallback.py`

If you even check the tutorial you are following you will notice they use `https://yourapp.com`

```
https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=7lstjK9NTyett_oeXtFiEQ&redirect_uri=https://yourapp.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please elaborate on the oauthcallback.py which you suggested as callback uri. Could you please tell me what should be inside the .py file?

Comment: Well if you are following OAuth with Zoom i would expect it to be that file.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that the redirect_uri in your /oauth request URL matches *exactly* that which is referenced in your oauth configuration/whitelist settings for Zoom.

Even the smallest difference like `http` vs `https` or including `wwww.`, etc. can throw an error. You might find some of the tips in this [OAuth Troubleshooting Guide](https://developers.miro.com/docs/troubleshooting-oauth20) helpful for other common OAuth errors to check, too!

The first item in that guide covers some common invalid redirect errors.